# I am trying to query the Contact apps on mac using python but can't find the right way

Tags: macos, contacts

I have a django app and I would like to allow users to import all their contacts in the app. I know that macOS stores contacts at `~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/AddressBook-v22.abcddb` but I am failing to query this DB in the right way.

I tried something like this but didn't work. Any help?

```
def main():
database = '~/Library/Application Support/AddressBook/AddressBook-v22.abcddb'

# create a database connection
conn = create_connection(database)
with conn:

    print("2. Query all tasks")
    select_all_tasks(conn)
```

Comment: If that is Python code, please indent it correctly and tag it as Python. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Use the PyObjC API to use the native Contacts framework instead of trying to read the SQLite db.